# Data lost on post request in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, session-cookies

The following problem only occurs when the web page is used by playwright (C#):

The web page contains a radio button that lets the user change the marital status of himself. When the radio button is used, the viewmodel is updated via session data (`Session.Set`). There is also a "Save" button to ultimately save the data in the database.
When using playwright, the radio button correctly sets the viewmodel to have the correct marital status, but as soon as the save button is clicked (post request), the updated data is set back to the old data.

Here is the backend code that saves the viewmodel as a session cookie:

```
public async Task<JsonResult> OnPostUpdateMaritalStatus(string maritalStatus)
{
try {
   var vm = GetSessionData();
   vm.MaritalStatus = maritalStatus;
   SaveSessionData(vm);
   vm = GetSessionData(); // This is to test if SaveSessionData does anything. It seems to 
   save it here correctly, but the data is lost in OnPostSaveBeneficiariesAsync()

   await HttpContext.Session.CommitAsync(); // Hasn't yielded any results.                 

   return new JsonResult("Pass");
}
catch (Exception)
{                 
   return new JsonResult("Fail");
   throw;
}
}
```

Here is `SaveSessionData()`:

```sql
private void SaveSessionData(BeneficiaryViewModel viewModel)
{
HttpContext.Session.Set(SessionString, viewModel);
}
```

Here is `OnPostSaveAsync` which is called after pressing the save button:

```vb
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostSaveBeneficiariesAsync()
{
string aeId = HttpContext.Session.GetString(ParticipantSessionStrings.AccountEnrollmentId);             

var viewModel = GetSessionData(); // Returns the old data as opposed to the correct data.

[...]
}
```

In `OnPostSaveAsync()` above, the `GetSessionData()` function retrieves the viewmodel:

```
private BeneficiaryViewModel GetSessionData()
{
return HttpContext.Session.Get<BeneficiaryViewModel>(SessionString);
}
```

Here is the playwright code, which selects the radio button with `checkmarks[0].ClickAsync()` and clicks the save button with await `page.Locator("input[id='save-changes-btn'].First.ClickAsync()`
Interestingly enough, if I add delays (commented out) in the playwright code, it works. So it seems as if it is a timing issue, but the web app should be resillient enough to serve a very fast user.

```vb
[Fact]
public async void BeneficiaryDesignation_ChangeMarriedToNonMarriedWithSpouse_StatusChanged()
        {
            // Setup
            Setup("evelyn", true, false, "Y");
            var page = await GoToBeneficiaries("evelyn");
            await Task.Delay(10000); // These delays are necessary because clicking too fast has shown to cause missing / unchanged viewmodel and session data.
            var checkmarks = await page.QuerySelectorAllAsync("span[class='checkmark']");
            Assert.True(checkmarks.Count == 2);
            await checkmarks[0].ClickAsync();
            await Task.Delay(10000); // These delays are necessary because clicking too fast has shown to cause missing / unchanged viewmodel and session data.
            await page.Locator("input[id='save-changes-btn']").First.ClickAsync();
            //await Task.Delay(10000);
            await page.Locator("input[id='confirm-button']").First.ClickAsync();
            //await Task.Delay(10000);
            var status = BeneficiaryUtils.GetCurrentMaritialStatus("evelyn");
            Assert.Equal("N", status.ToUpper());
            // Teardown
            await page.CloseAsync();
            Reset();
        }
```

Things I have tried:

- Calling `HttpContext.Session.CommitAsync()` in `OnPostUpdateMaritalStatus`
- I checked whether it is a problem with the playwright browser itself, but it isnt, because if I use said browser and click through manually, it works. Only when the playwright library clicks through, it doesnt work.
- **Add delays in the playwright code. This worked which implies that it could be a timing or synchronization issue, but the application should be resillient enough to handle playwright's speed.**

Comment: TBH it is very far from being a [mre]. Are you sure that `ClickAsync` waits for page being reloaded? Can you post a [mre] somewhere like github?

Comment: I am unsure as how I would be able to do that, as this is a an enterprise level application with a large codebase. 
About `ClickAsync()`: Yes I am sure because I can visually see playwright selecting the radio button. Just quicker than a real user which seems to throw off the app.

I am moreso looking for pointers here as to what else it could be, as opposed to an actual solution to the problem, if that makes sense. I just ran out of ideas of what it could be.

But maybe you have a suggestion.

Comment: It is hard to tell. Note that you don't need Playwright to test the scenario. Personally I would try to repro it by calling corresponding methods in succession via simple http client and checking the results. Also try enabling logging in the app for requests and check out the timeline.